# Can a silent letter be employed?

Tags: meaning, silent-letter

In my [question on silent *e*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/960/94), ctype.h's answer includes this:

> A silent *e* is often employed to modify the pronunciation of the preceding vowel, functioning much like a diacritic would in many other languages.

I know people are employed by companies, but can a silent letter be *employed*?

Comment: I initially thought "A dictionary could best answer this", but [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/employ#Verb) only refers to the employment of people in its meaning of "use".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes. "employed" or rather "employ" as a verb has effectively the same meaning as "to use" or "to make use of", but with a connotation towards the item not being consumed in the process.

Obviously the major use of the word employ is in the sentences like

> I employ two members of staff

In this case, both members of staff would be referred to as *employees* and I would be their *employer*, however it is entirely valid to use it in other contexts where an item (particularly an intangible one) is used:

> I was losing my game of Chess with Kasperov until I employed the Queens-Rook defence.
>
> We employed a new technique to defeating our competitors last week.
>
> I wrote a strongly worded letter to the CEO last week, in which I employed some decidedly untactful remarks.