# How is the word 'meme' pronounced in english? Or how would a native pronounce it?

Tags: pronunciation

As a spanish native I've always pronounced putting emphasis in every single letter, but when it comes to english... I have no clue of how to say this word.

Comment: For a more general answer, read http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/960/when-to-pronounce-e

Comment: **Where you're lucky**: Spanish has a regular, intelligible orthography; **where you're unlucky**: you're trying to learn English, which is about as far from that as can be imagined.

Comment: @Robusto well, actually we study english since we are 4-5 years old, I was just wondering if it had a different pronunciation as it is a non-formal (?) word.... also, I started german lessons, that it is way far from spanish :D

Comment: @Sergi: Well, then would you say you've learned it already? ^_^

Comment: Just wanted to say that because I (a native BrE speaker) only encountered this word in written form for about 10 years before hearing it said aloud, I have only recently learned it's correct pronunciation. My internal monologue still pronounces it me-mae and I have to correct myself if I want to use it aloud.

Answer (score 3):

If you can understand the International Phonetic Alphabet, the pronunciation is

/ˈmiːm/

Otherwise, in simpler terms, it rhymes with **team**, as in, 'football team'.

Comment: This isn't IPA. I've seen e with macron used for the English "long e" sound in some dictionaries' own phonetic systems, but IPA uses the more typical Latinate pairs of vowel signs and vowel sounds, in which the "long e" of "meme" (and "team") is [i].

Comment: @Tim: actually it's [mi:m] to show the long vowel. So mike made four mistakes in six glyphs: (i) using backslashes; (ii) showing the stress on a monosyllabic word; (iii) [e] instead of [i]; and (iv) indicating vowel length with a macron instead of a colon. Mistake number (iii) is the most heinous, because it will leave the OP genuinely confused about how to pronounce 'meme'.